# How to pick a specialization

Tags: the-division-2

I've just recently hit level 30 and completed all main missions that I'm aware of, minus two strongholds. There's no indication that I have to have completed the strongholds as well (although they're my next step)

According to sources online such as [this one](https://thedivision.fandom.com/wiki/Specializations), you should receive your specialization at level 30 and get to pick one of the three.

However, I've been level 30 and received multiple caches for continuing to level up, yet no indication of where my specialization is.

**Where/How do I choose a specialization?**

Comment: Hmm. Not sure how I missed that other one. :/

Answer (score 2):

What you're missing is probably one or several of the strongholds. Have a look below.

> In order to unlock Specializations in The Division 2, you'll need to
>   reach the beginning of the endgame. You'll need to:
>
> - Reach level 30
> - Complete the District Union Arena, Roosevelt Island, and Capitol    Building Strongholds
>
> Once those are complete, you'll receive a call to head back to the
>   White House. Head to the table on your immediate left, by the vendor
>   that lets you allocate skill points and SHD Tech points, and you'll be
>   able to pick up your first Specialization weapon. Don't forget that
>   you can switch to the other Specializations at any time, just head
>   back to that particular vendor.

[Source](http://www.pushsquare.com/news/2019/03/guide_the_division_2_-_how_to_unlock_specializations)

Comment: I'll test it out next time I get the chance and if this holds true I'll accept it. I only finished one of the strongholds. I just don't like that there is no clear indication that you have to finish them as well.

Comment: I'll need to check but I believe there was like a mission planner that gave you an indication about the Specializations but I could be wrong It's been a while.